# Angular.js smart table loading symbol during ajax call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp

Using the pipe/ajax plugin example at http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website I have been trying to implement an Angular.js smart table with a loading indicator whilst my ajax call is still loading.

angular-boostrap.js

```
var eposWebAngularStrutsApp = angular.module('eposWebAngularStrutsApp', ['ngResource','smart-table']);
```

angular-controller.js

```
eposWebAngularStrutsApp.controller('StoreHealthCheckController', ['$scope','StoreServerHealth', function ($scope, StoreServerHealth) {
    //http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-crud-app-minutes-angulars-resource/

    var ctrl = this;
    this.displayed = [];

    this.callServer = function callServer(tableState) {

        ctrl.isLoading = true;
        StoreServerHealth.query(function(result) {          
            ctrl.displayed = result.data;
            ctrl.isLoading = false;
          }); //query() returns all the entries    
    };  

}]);
```

angular-service.js

```
eposWebAngularStrutsApp.factory('StoreServerHealth', function($resource) {
      return $resource('json/storeHealthCheckList.action'); // Note the full endpoint address
    });
```

My JSP...

```
<table class="table table-striped" st-pipe="mc.callServer" st-table="mc.displayed" ng-controller="StoreHealthCheckController">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Store</th>
        <th>Server</th>
        <th>Conn Status</th>
        <th>Last Updated</th>
        <th>MDI</th>
        <th>Last Synched (MDI)</th>
        <th>DSM</th>
        <th>Last Synched (DSM)</th>
        <th>Trading Status</th>
        <th>Build</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-show="!mc.isLoading">
    <tr ng-repeat="row in mc.displayed">
        <td>{{row.locationId}}</td>
        <td>{{row.clientId}}</td>
        <td>{{row.status}}</td>
        <td>{{row.displayLastUpdateTime}}</td>
        <td>{{row.replicationStatus}}</td>
        <td>{{row.displayLastReplicationSyncTime}}</td>
        <td>{{row.dsmReplicationStatus}}</td>
        <td>{{row.dsmLastSynchTime}}</td>
        <td>{{row.storeTradingStatus}}</td>
        <td>{{row.buildVersion}}</td>   
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody ng-show="mc.isLoading">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="10" class="text-center">Loading ... </td>
    </tr>   
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But I keep getting an error TypeError: href is null firebug/content/debugger/stackFrame/StackFrame.js.

Can someone let me know what I might be doing wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: Why you don't have an alias to controller? I thonk you should add this: `ng-controller="StoreHealthCheckController as mc"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment posted above was the answer to this question. I had forgotten to Alias the controller.